# SQL Server Date time conversion giving incorrect result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 6 digit value in one column that I need to convert to date-time. I tried two different formula given below.

1. `(DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, COLUMNNAME)-((1000*(CONVERT(int, COLUMNNAME)/100)))-1, DATEADD(year, CONVERT(int, COLUMNNAME/1000), '1 Jan 1900'))) as Order_date`

But this is giving following error message:-

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow. [SQLSTATE=22007, SQLERRORCODE=517]

2. `convert(datetime, (convert (int, COLUMNNAME)), 6) as Order_date`

And this is giving incorrect value for date. There is one particular value 118150 that should result into `2018-05-30 :00:00:00`, but my statement is returning `2223-06-27 00:00:00`

Can anybody please help what is causing error with first statement and how can I modify it to run on entire table.

Comment: And what is the format of 118150?

Comment: what is the datatype of this column ? And more important, cant you make it data type date or datetime ?

Comment: WHat is the source of this? Unix timestamp? Oracle? ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the date format correctly, this will work:

```
select dateadd(day, x % 1000 - 1, datefromparts(1900 + x / 1000, 1, 1))
from (values (118150)) v(x)
```

Comment: Looks good... bute nevertheless: never seen this format before.

Comment: It worked like charm. I encountered it in ETL and I had no access to source table to check data type or all values. Thanks a lot...